# draggable not working on touch device?

Tags: jquery, touch, mouseevent

Here is jsfiddle link  ***[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/maCmB/1/)***

```
$("#outer").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    var inner = $("<div/>", {
        class: "inner"
    }).draggable().appendTo("#outer");
    inner.css("position", "absolute");
    e.type = "mousedown.draggable";
    e.target = inner[0];
    inner.css("left", e.pageX);
    inner.css("top", e.pageY);
    inner.trigger(e);
    return false;
});

<div id="outer">
</div>
```

Can anyone help to support on touch device?

Comment: You can try the plugin:
http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 0):

Bind events 'touchstart' for touch devices and 'mousedown' for desktop. Thus it will work for both devices.
Hence we can write :

```
 $("#outer").bind("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {

     //Your code...

});
```

Comment: only append the div ,when bind touchstart event ,drag not working on touchmove

Comment: e.type = "mousedown.draggable"; was used ..... which will not work for the devices..